# Two different project for one App in Play Store

Tags: android, deployment, google-play, apk, keystore

I have a project deployed in the Google Play Store.
I have a very HUGE refactoring to do so the best thing is to restart from a blank project.

I want to build the apk with this new project and deploy it in the play store in place of the apk created with my first project since it will be exactly the same app. How can I be sure there will be no problems when i'll deploy the apk  compiled in my new project ? i first think it has to be the same package name and applicationid, what else ?

Comment: same keystore  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- same package name (same applicationId);
- versionCode > current one in App Store;
- signed with the same Key;

After that you can publish the app as an update for the current app.

Comment: and build version from the store increased by 1